# Parse numbers out of file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

```
header
//
SeqT: {"POS-s":174.683, "time":0.0130084}
SeqT: {"POS-s":431.49, "time":0.0221447}
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001);
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993);
absolute:
gthcont: 5 4 2 1 3 4 543 5  67 657  78 67 8  5645 6 
01010010101010101010101010101011111100011
1111010010010101010101010111101000100000
00000000000000011001100101010010101011111
```

In the moment I am splitting like this

```
!body && /^\/\/$/              {body=1}
body  && sub(/^gthcont: */,"") {print > "second_"FILENAME}
body  && /^[01]+/              {print > "third_"FILENAME}
body  && /^\[[0-9]+\]/ {
    print > "first_"FILENAME
    print substr($0, 2, index($0,"]")-2) > "fourth_"FILENAME
}
```

Which produces four files with the first file

```
[25]:0.00843832,469:0.0109533):0.00657864,((((872:0.00120503,((980:0.0001);
[29]:((962:0.000580339,930:0.000580339):0.00543993);
```

The second file has to be

```
5 4 2 1 3 4 543 5  67 657  78 67 8  5645 6
```

The next file

```
01010010101010101010101010101011111100011
11110100100101010101010101111010001000001
00000000000000011001100101010010101011111
```

the fourth file just has the numbers in the brackets

```
25
29
```

I would need a fifth file to be produced with two colums (space seperated)

```
174.683 0.00130084
431.49 0.0221447
```

so these are the two numbers of the lines  always starting with SeqT and always is the first column after "POS-S" and the other after time...how can i get that into the awk script?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind this and also what your problem is ?

Comment: well i just need to extract 174.683 0.00130084 in additon to the rest...it is a completely reproduceable example...

Answer (score 1):

You could add another statement to you program along the lines of this:

```
sub(/^SeqT: {"POS-s":/,"") && sub(/, "time":/," ") && sub(/}$/,"") {print >"fifth_"FILENAME}
```

`sub` returns true if a substitution is performed, so if each of the substitutions is successful (and the block is therefore executed), you are left with the two numbers separated by a space.

As rightly pointed out in the comments, if there are lines in the header section that may also match these three patterns, then you should also add the `body` condition, i.e. `body && sub(/^Seqt...`.

Comment: doid you realise the previous question and this question are related? ... as I asked for the awk thing previously? if not just tell me....or if youd id tell me as well :-p  - i mean before I posted that comment...

Comment: I dare say that it wouldn't _need_ to but yes, it might be useful. And yes, I recognise my code in the question :)

Comment: I didn't think that it was relevant!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to match:

```
SeqT: {"POS-s":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?), "time":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)}
```

And substitute with `$1 $2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kR1nM2/1)

Script:

```
body  && sub(/SeqT: {"POS-s":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?), "time":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)}/,"$1 $2") {print > "fifth_"FILENAME}
```

Comment: Nice regex but it doesn't really fully answer the question, as the OP is looking to add to their existing awk script.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of awk you're using, as I don't think that any of them support lookahead assertions in regex or capture groups with `sub`...Have you tested your answer?